# Dell Precision 4600 - Ubuntu 20.04 - Internal Mic & Bluetooth Headphone Mic Not Working

Tags: microphone

Having installed Ubuntu since last year, everything worked on my PC like it did on my removed Windows 10 OS except the inbuilt mic:

Below is my device configuration:

```
~$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard Audio
    Subsystem: Dell Precision M4600 [1028:04a3]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0bea] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GF108 High Definition Audio Controller [1028:14a3]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

I also queried my audio devices using this command `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` below is my result:

```
cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: IDT 92HD90BXX
Codec: Nvidia GPU 14 HDMI/DP
Codec: Nvidia GPU 14 HDMI/DP
Codec: Nvidia GPU 14 HDMI/DP
Codec: Nvidia GPU 14 HDMI/DP
```

I also downloaded vokoscreen to check pulse and alsa-server options and also test, the tests produced failed results without audio tone captured at all except noise.

See screenshots of my test options below:
[image: Audio Devices listed]
[image: Attempt to test NVidia MIC was showing Device is Busy]
[image]

The final step I tool after testing with VokoScreen with failure was to download QasMixer, upon opening QasMixer, I have the screenshot below:
[image: QasMixer]

Initially, when I open QasMixer, the Mic line with 12:00db was not selected at all, so I selected it, meaning I enabled, all this efforts only resulted in the MIC icon showing at the top right of my screen next the speaker icon with volume indicator but mic is still not working.

What else could I be doing wrong.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I had to query the specification of the hardware devices using the command:

> I determined the hardware devices on my pc by running the command below in terminal:
> `$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec`

I eventually had to remove all about alsa tools I had installed before using
`sudo apt-get remove alsa-tools-gui`

Then I added the line below into the last line of my alsa-base.conf file using the command :: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

> options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=dell-precision enable=1

After uninstalling Alsa & alsa-gui-utils which I have been using to test the audio devices using VokoScreen. I then had to remove alsa/alsautils and installed PulseAudio & PulseEffects back because my speaker which was working before I started troubleshooting the mic issue stopped working as well as soon as I removed pulseaudio.

After installation PulseAudio & PulseEffects using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y pavucontrol

sudo apt-get install -y pulseaudio

sudo apt-get -y install pulseeffects
```

After installation, I tried loading `pavucontrol` from terminal, it came up with the interface but did not load up the dashboard, it kept saying "device is busy". So I decided to restart.

After restarting, suddenly, everything was detected in the top right section and my mic and speaker started working again.

Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have your HDMI as your sound device, so unless your mic is plugged into the monitor , it won't work, you need to change it to whatever your chipset is, not Nvidia.

Comment: Wow! Well it was not working before as well anyway. Before I did all the above, my sound was working normally except mic. But now my sound and mic has stopped working. What do you advise.?

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to resolve it, I documented what I did in the answer I posted, please accept it as a valid answer.

Comment: You were actually right about this, I switched it from the chipset mic to the dedicated GPU mic during the troubleshooting just for testing purpose.